# I want to implement priority queue (insert,delete,find) project with switch case for my assignment please can anyone help me?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

> here is the code/ also here [pastebin code list][1]: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/h6gM8yP8Q2/

I want to implement a priority queue (insert, delete, find) project with a switch case for my assignment please can anyone help me?

Actually, I am trying to do using queue into switch case

1. add new entry by gquiz.push()
2. delte gquiz.pop()
3. find gquiz.top()  //minumum value will show

i already added the code option but maybe gquiz.pop() not work in the switch case. if not then how I will do that?

Please, help to solve the project.

Thank you.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

void showpq(
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > gq)
{
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>,greater<int> > g = gq;
    while (!g.empty()) {
        cout << '\t' << g.top();
        g.pop();
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>,greater<int> > gquiz;

    while(1)
    {

    int choice;

    cout<<"what do you want to do?\n"
                "\n"
                "1. Insert\n"
                "2. Find\n"
                "3. Delete\n"
                "4. Show Queue\n \nchoice your option from above: ";
    cin>>choice;

    switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                int n;
                cout<<"Enter the value: " ;
                cin>>n;// Option 2 => Insert
                gquiz.push(n);
                break;
            case 2:
                gquiz.top();
                if(!gquiz.empty()){
                    gquiz.top(); // Find the minimum number.
                }else{
                    cout<<"Empty Priority Queue"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(!gquiz.empty()){
                    gquiz.pop(); //Delete the minimum number from the queue
                    cout<<"Successfully Deleted"<<endl;
                }else{
                    cout<<"There is not element to delete"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if(!gquiz.empty()){
                    showpq(gquiz); // Show full queue
                }else{
                    cout<<"There is not element to delete"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"\nYou are terminated!!! \nYou entered wrong input.\n"<<endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code cannot show the `priority_queue` after `gquiz.pop();`. You may want some loop to repeat the choice and switch statement.

Comment: yes i know it not working but I  want to my code like this.

Comment: Please define "like this". What kind of modification is allowed?

Comment: example, in the case 1: i want insert  the new entry into queue using gquiz.push() function from switch case. case 1:
                    cout<<"Enter the value"<<endl;
                    cin>>n;// Option 2 => Insert
                    gquiz.push(n);
                    break;

Comment: OK `gquiz.pop();` should be working. Check it with debugger. Actually you didn't complain about `gquiz.push(n);` while the result is also invisible. No modification is needed.

Comment: Ah, I found your code actually don't work because `n` is used without declaration. Declare the variable to make your code work.

Comment: here, user will input new value into "n" cin>>n; then "gquiz.push(n);" will insert a new entry and when we will show the entire queue it will show full queue entries

Comment: ohh, right insert is working not. but still more options not working. Please, stay with me to solve it

Comment: using "gquiz.top();" i want to show the minimum number but now working

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Please focus on a specific issue, one that you can describe with expected and actual results, along with trimmed-down code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Now I found that you are actually using a loop. How bad your indentation is!

Comment: I am Sorry JaMiT, in the case 2 i want to show the minimun number from the queue but in my case it's' now working.

Comment: There is no statements to show the minimum value. You should use `cout` to show that like you did in other places.

Comment: Mr,  MikeCAT this my assignment requirement that, I have to implement the priority queue for Insert, Find and Delete queue entry value from the queue. I tried something like that. If you tech me high valuable code then I will thy it.

Comment: As i know i added the queue ascending order so if I use exp: queue.top, then will should show the minimum value.

Comment: in the switch case every statement working except this gquiz.top();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the program just sharing for otheres. Thank you – Mr. MikeCAT

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
void showpq(
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > gq)
{
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>,greater<int> > g = gq;
    while (!g.empty()) {
        cout << '\t' << g.top();
        g.pop();
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>,greater<int> > gquiz;
    while(1)
    {

    int choice;
    cout<<"\nwhat do you want to do?\n"
                "\n"
                "1. Insert\n"
                "2. Find\n"
                "3. Delete\n"
                "4. Show Queue\n \nchoice your option from above: ";
    cin>>choice;

    switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                int n;
                cout<<"Enter the value: " ;
                cin>>n;// Option 2 => Insert
                gquiz.push(n);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(!gquiz.empty()){
                    cout<<"\n"<<gquiz.top()<<" is the minimum number"<<endl; // Find the minimum number.
                }else{
                    cout<<"\nEmpty Priority Queue"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(!gquiz.empty()){
                    gquiz.pop(); //Delete the minimum number from the queue
                    cout<<"\nSuccessfully Deleted"<<endl;
                }else{
                    cout<<"\nThere is no element to delete"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if(!gquiz.empty()){
                    showpq(gquiz); // Show full queue
                }else{
                    cout<<"\nEmpty Priority Queue"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"\nYou are terminated!!! \nYou entered wrong input.\n"<<endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers rarely help others. Just like questions, answers should primarily use prose to explain the main points, with code serving as supplemental illustration. It is understandable that some answers need to lean on code more than questions should, but they should not rely solely on code.